# Substract specific parameter from url java

Tags: java

I need to substract an specific parameter (urlReturn) from a URL like this :

`http://somedomain.mx/th=6048000&campus=A&matric=L01425785&serv=GRAD&count=2&per=TEST&passwd=69786e720c0f0e&mount=1000.00&urlReturn=http://somedomain.mx:7003/SP/app/login.xhtml?id=1234&mat=2323&fh=05012014124755&store=TESO`

My final string should look like this:

`String urlReturn = http://somedomain.mx:7003/SP/app/login.xhtml?id=1234&mat=2323;`

And the rest of the string should look like this:

`String urlReturn2 = http://somedomain.mx/th=6048000&campus=A&matric=L01425785&serv=GRAD&count=2&per=TEST&passwd=69786e720c0f0e&mount=1000.00&fh=05012014124755&store=TESO`

I currently have this :

```
String string = string.toString().split("\\&")[0];
```

But the urlReturn parameter should always come as the first one.

Comment: And what have you done?

Comment: Show us what you have done. It'd take a one substring and a couple of indexOf to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (s is your original String):

```
 urlReturn = s.substring(0, s.indexOf("&urlReturn=")).replace("&urlReturn=", "");
 urlReturn2 = s.substring(s.indexOf("&urlReturn=")).replace("&urlReturn=", "");
```

Definitely not elegant at all, but working. I really need some sleep now so take my anser carefully :) You may alswo wanto to check if the parameters is in the String s via the contains method to avoid index out of bounds exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

use [string#split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

```
url.split("\\?")[1];
```

Comment: This doesn't produce anything that's close to what OP is asking for.

Comment: @Keppil it lets him extract a part that he needs. He'd of course need to split again to get the first part, but I'm not going to do all the work for him. And I wouldn't bother with regex because if he's asking this it's probably beyond his skillset for the time being.

Comment: No, it lets him extract a part of what he needs, while discarding parts of what he wants to keep.

Comment: @Keppil you can still do another split on the same original string and then concatenate things together